# Retrieve data from a specific row

Tags: mysql, row, where-clause

I'm trying to get data from a specific row from my database.
And I get the error:

> Unknown column 'Apalm' in 'where clause'

This is my code:

```
 $naam = $_GET['naam'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM planten WHERE naam = $naam")
 or die(mysql_error());
```

And the picture below shows my database.

[image: phpmyadmin]

It seems like the script thinks the row is called "Apalm". But I clearly stated to search in 'naam'?

This is probably very easy to fix, but I just can't seem to find it on Google.
So please help me, or point me in the right direction. I'm very eager to learn this!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a comment: you shouldn't execute queries building text in that way, 'cause it's not `sql injection` free; use parameters instead and avoid several headaches...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`naam` column seems to be a text, so enclose its value between single quotes within the sql code as well:

```
"SELECT * FROM planten WHERE naam = '$naam'"
```

However, pls consider using either proper escaping or prepared statements to prevent sql injection.

Comment: You're completely right, but queries like that aren't sql injection safe! Using parameters you are not forced to put quotes or format dates and you avoid sql injection too...

Comment: @Marco I know and I also called the OP's attention to that.

Comment: Thank you sir! This did the trick. Such a stupid little mistake.

I'll also look into the prepared statements!